# Spring Batch PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources() not working for https url

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, spring-batch, partitioning

I am trying to read multiple csv files present on "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shrutika09/SpringBatchTemplateUploaderPOC/main/order-data-*.csv" and insert the same into database parallelly using Spring Batch.

When I use the URL for a single csv file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shrutika09/SpringBatchTemplateUploaderPOC/main/order-data-1.csv), all records are read and inserted into database.
But when I try to read all files with a particular naming pattern (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shrutika09/SpringBatchTemplateUploaderPOC/main/order-data-*.csv), it doesn't recognizes the file and hence doesn't work as expected.

Is there any way where we can read all files matching a particular naming pattern from a github location.

I am using Spring Batch Partitioner

```
Partitioner:
@Bean
    public Partitioner partitioner() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In Partitioner");
        MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        partitioner.setResources(resolver.getResources("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shrutika09/SpringBatchTemplateUploaderPOC/main/order-data-*.csv"));
        partitioner.partition(5);
        return partitioner;
    }

Reader: 
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Orders> reader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String path)
            throws MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println("In Reader");
        System.out.println("In Reader" +path);
        FlatFileItemReader<Orders> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Orders>();

        reader.setResource(new UrlResource(path));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Orders>() {
            {
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                    {
                        setNames(new String[] { "id", "firstName", "lastName" });
                    }
                });
                setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Orders>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(Orders.class);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return reader;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your example and indeed it works with a single resource but not with a wildcard. I get: `[main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shrutika09/SpringBatchTemplateUploaderPOC/main/] in the file system: URL [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shrutika09/SpringBatchTemplateUploaderPOC/main/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shrutika09/SpringBatchTemplateUploaderPOC/main/
`

Comment: It seems that the resolver looks for resources in the local file system when using a wildcard. This is not related to Spring Batch per se, it's rather a Spring Framework question. So I will let someone from the Spring Framework team help you on that.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine Thank You. It would be great help in that case. Please let me know if anyone can help this.